# What is the default installation directory with an MSI install of Python 2.7?

Tags: python, windows, installation-path

When using windows MSI installation from python.org/download (current version is 2.7.3), python by default installs in some folder but it is nowhere documented what is this default. Can someone check that on windows?

Also does this MSI installation recognizes is it 32 or 64bit windows and installs appropriate version or it assumes that it shall always be 32bit version of python?

Particularly I am interested what happens on Windows 7 when this installer is used.

Comment: C:\Python27 is the default installation directory.
There are different binaries for 32/64bit installations, you need to choose which one you want to download.

Comment: My installs typically go to `C:\PythonXX`, where `XX` is the version number.

Comment: it is no doubt on particular 32/64 bit "zip" installation but MSI installation does not specify which one it is.

Comment: can someone confirm where exe's are (in c:\python27\bin or in installation folder c:\python27\ ?) and what are their exact names - i know that there is python.exe and pythonw.exe which corresponds to dos/windows python "idle"

Comment: my bad, there is 64bit msi installer, I have just realized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the default installation folder is c:/python27

Comment: both are installed in the same directory, it just depends on which one you choose